# Can't install Crunchbang

Tags: system-installation, usb, crunchbang

I wanted to install Crunchbang 11 x64 from my USB (8GB, fat32), but when the installer starts, it aborts because the installer doesn't find a Crunchbang CD in my drive. I tried it via the `dd` command on Kubuntu and I tried it with Unetbootin on Kubuntu and Windows and I tried the universal USB installer on Windows, but nothing works.

Is there any way to get rid of this problem without installing from a CD? (I don't have one and don't want to buy one right now :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. I recon that you have used the following command to copy the image to the usb drive? Ref. [#! WIKI](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/statler_usb_installation)

`sudo dd if=/path/to/iso/crunchbang-10-20101205-openbox-i686.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M;sync`

Be sure that the of= is the device and not the partition since you have partitioned the device. This would be if you use `/dev/sdx1` which is the first partition on the device. It also sounds strange that you would get an error message during the installer which informs that the installer doesn't find a Crunchbang CD. Have you pressed F11 (the normal keybind for boot menu) and chosen to boot from USB?

Last of all, it would be nice to have the error you are getting to debug this issue. Press the ALT-F1/ALT-F2.. buttons to switch term if you get to the installer, where which you could probably find an error message.

Hope this could help.

Comment: With the error message i meant that there is an error while detcting Disk Drives.

Comment: And when i try to boot in live mode i get the message on my screen: modprobe:module swap not found in modules.dep